# Receiving DMX512 on STM32F103C8

Tags: stm32

tl;dr: trying to receive DMX512 (via a RS485 module) on a STM32 and not going well.

I am trying to modify the firmware of a commercial lighting fixture with a STM32F103C8 clone as it's MCU. It basically receives DMX and converts it into a single axis of motion and a lighting fixture with ~24 WS2812B LEDs. Unfortunately, all of the DMX libraries available (DMXSimple2, Conceptinetics) only support avr, and I don't have very much experience with the lower level hardware/library interactions.

I am looking at [this tutorial](https://playground.arduino.cc/DMX/Ardmx/) because it seems easier to modify to work with the STM32, but the tutorial says

> Now just do a search for "ISR(USARTn_RX_vect)" in HardwareSerial.cpp

which I can't find in the [Arduino STM32 core](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32).

Can someone help or point me towards resources about how to modify the existing libraries to work for my application?

Comment: Are you using Arduino STM32 core or STM32 HALs?